# Reading text file variables and updated assigned values

Tags: java, file, parsing

I have a text file which has text as follows:

```
emVersion = "1.32.4.0";
 ecdbVersion = "1.8.9.6";
 ReleaseVersion = "2.3.2.0";
```

I want to update the version number by taking the input from a user if user enter the new value for emVersion as 1.32.5.0 then

`emVersion` in text file will be updated as `emVersion = "1.32.5.0";`

All this I have to do using java code. What I have done till now is reading text file line by line then in that searching the word emVersion if found the broken line into words and then replace the token 1.32.4.0 but it is not working because spaces are unequal in the file.

Code what i have written is :

public class UpdateVariable {

```
public static void main(String s[]){
    String replace = "1.5.6";
String UIreplace = "\""+replace+"\"";
     File file =new File("C:\\Users\\310256803\\Downloads\\setup.rul");
    Scanner in = null;
    try {
        in = new Scanner(file);
        while(in.hasNext())
        {
            String line=in.nextLine();
            if(line.contains("svEPDBVersion"))
            {
                String [] tokens = line.split("\\s+");
                String var_1 = tokens[0];
                String var_2 = tokens[1];
    String var_3 = tokens[2];
    String var_4 = tokens[3];
    String OldVersion = var_3;
    String NewVersion = UIreplace;
    try{
    String content = IOUtils.toString(new FileInputStream(file), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    content = content.replaceAll(OldVersion, NewVersion);
    IOUtils.write(content, new FileOutputStream(file), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: What means "spaces are unequal in the file"? Which output do you expect and what do you get? And show at least the code, which writes your (wrong) output.

Answer (score 0):

```
    //---this code changes each version's values but the is a option to keep the old value.
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    File file = new File("versions.txt");

    ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] arr =
    {
        "emVersion", "ecdbVersion", "releaseVersion"
    };

    String line = "";
    String userInput = "";

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));)
    {
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            data.add(line);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter new " + arr[i] + " number or (s) to keep the old value.");
            userInput = in.nextLine();

            line = data.get(i);
            String version = line.substring(0, line.indexOf(" "));


            if (arr[i].equalsIgnoreCase(version))
            {
                arr[i] = line.replace(line.subSequence(line.indexOf("= "), line.indexOf(";")), "= \"" + userInput + "\"");
            }

            if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("s"))
            {
                arr[i] = line;
            }

        }

        PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file, false));
        printWriter.println(arr[0]);
        printWriter.println(arr[1]);
        printWriter.println(arr[2]);
        printWriter.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: It works fine when there is no space before ecdbVersion and ReleaseVersion but as i have shown in text file spaces are there before edbVersion so it is not working for that :( @Lyle

Comment: So you want it to have the exact same output, with the spaces? or can it be without spaces?

Comment: the text file should remain as it is only the versions should change @Lyle

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expression  eg:- line.trim().split("\s*=\s*"); . If it does not work please let me know , i will provide you complete solution.